# my input in html does not start from the top

Tags: html, css

So I have a question about the input line I made the other day.

When adjusting the `height` of the input, rather than start at the top, the text is centered vertically. Additionally, the text does not stop at the outer most edge of the box and continue on a new line, but instead continues without wrapping.

```css
.text-form {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input class="text-form" type='text' name='inputter' placeholder='bla'>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: So you want a tall text box but you want it to only have 1 line of text?

Comment: Why not just use a `<textarea>`?

Comment: @csmckelvey I guess you could say that, just like  for example Word that just starts at the top and stops at the right end en continues on a new line

Comment: @TylerRoper I am still working with the old HTML4, not HTML 5.

Comment: @J.Teurlings `<textarea>` has been around since the dawn of time.

Comment: @TylerRoper It is more that i am lokoing for alternatives because i want to learn the fundamentals

Comment: Applying wonky CSS workarounds to recreate preexisting, fully-supported, user-familiar HTML elements seems like the opposite of fundamentals, however "to each their own". While I don't condone it, I may be able to answer it.

Answer (score -2):

You can try fiddling with `padding-bottom` in place of setting a `height`:

```css
input {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="foo bar">
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
Input {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```